# Greoli Ethereum node not sync

Tags: linux

I would like to start a Node ETH with Groeli network.
For that, I'am using the last version of GETH 1.10.25.

The problem is when I start the GETH with :
geth --http --goerli --http.port 8547 --http.vhosts "*" --http.api eth,web3,debug,txpool,net,admin,debug,personal --allow-insecure-unlock --datadir /home/goerli

The node do not sync even if I wait for hours, with logs :

```
INFO [10-06|21:24:10.757] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=32 static=0
INFO [10-06|21:24:20.795] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=43 static=0
INFO [10-06|21:24:30.942] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=35 static=0
INFO [10-06|21:24:40.946] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=33 static=0
INFO [10-06|21:24:50.980] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=39 static=0
WARN [10-06|21:25:14.491] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=6ec80bbf err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:25:20.174] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=836158fb err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:28:04.293] Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
WARN [10-06|21:29:13.651] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=609616bb err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:31:03.978] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=64abe7ac err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:31:04.981] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=785d7224 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:32:10.873] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=421e4d7c err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:33:04.334] Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
WARN [10-06|21:33:37.801] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=4789efb3 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:36:23.193] Dropping unsynced node during sync       id=12f7cc945f83c697 conn=dyndial addr=X.X.X.X:33333 type=Geth/v1.10.23-stable...
WARN [10-06|21:36:35.400] Dropping unsynced node during sync       id=5223786ec37decfb conn=inbound addr=X.X.X.X:48522 type=Geth/v1.10.3-stable-...
WARN [10-06|21:36:46.589] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=9d4f3150 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:36:54.640] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=020ad183 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:38:04.372] Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
WARN [10-06|21:39:46.269] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=a90b10c7 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:40:42.179] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=327cb76d err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:43:04.410] Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
WARN [10-06|21:43:46.341] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=e2d00418 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:44:36.840] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=bd651303 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:44:51.081] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=77f50e04 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:47:36.564] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=cbd3f861 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [10-06|21:48:04.444] Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
```

Someone already got this problem ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Not sure what to do.